# how can i add data in jasper report using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, report

my problem is i am using hibernate createsqlquery to fetch data fromdatabase

and from this i am getting a list og object array like

```
List<Object[]> listdata = createsqlquery(query).list;
```

now i have to use this listdata in the jasper to generate pdf.

how can i do it

pls help

Answer (score 1):

Try following, hope it helps.

Create a bean to hold your returned data from hibernate

Say for eg **MyBean.java**

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{
private Integer id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}
}
```

Now use **MyBean** to hold the data and use it to fill the report as following

```
List<MyBean> listdata = createsqlquery(query).list;

JasperDesign jasperDesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign(reportStream);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = ;//your list here
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listdata));

//You can export generated report as follows
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,pathToExport);
```

**Note:** You will need mapping for **MyBean.java** for hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your `List<Object[]>` (returned by the query) into a `List<SomeBean>`, and then use a [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html).

For each field of your report, you'll need a corresponding getter in your bean. For example, the field `$F{firstName}` will call the method `getFirstName()` of the bean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
List<Object[]> listdata = createsqlquery(query).list;

JasperDesign jasperDesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign(reportStream);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listdata);//your list here
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,ds);
```

I hope this helps